# how to convert this mysql query in sequelize format

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, sequelize.js

I know all the basic sequelize operations, but how to convert a complex query with lot of when cases, and, or etc. Here i'm giving my mysql query,

```
select * 
from `timer` 
where 
  email = 'abcd@gmail.com' 
  and o_id = 'CBADCKDSFO2'  
  and (hour > 8 or (hour = 8 and minute > 27))  
  and (
    (case 
      when dom is not null and mon is not null then dom = 21 and mon = 6  
      when dom is not null and mon is null then dom = 21 
      when dom is null and mon is null then CAST(dow as CHAR(50)) like '%ABC%' end) 
    or 
    (dom is null and mon is null and dow is null )
  ) 
  and act = 5 
order by hour, minute;
```

I tried this one. But it has some issues,

```
tables.findAll({
    where: {
        email: <email_id>,
        o_id: <o_id>,
        act: 5,
        attributes: { include: [[tables.sequelize.literal('case when dom is not null and mon is not null then dom = 21 and mon = 6  when dom is not null and mon is null then dom = 21 when dom is null and mon is null then CAST(dow as CHAR(50)) like '%ABC%' end')]]},
        hour: {[gt]: 8},
        [Op.or]:{
            {hour: 10},
            {minute: {[gt]: 27}}
        }
    }
});
```

I need to convert this into sequelize orm format without using raw query type. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far

Comment: Updated the question.